# Python- Remaining values in list after value has occurred x times

Tags: python, list, loops

So far I have:

```
list = [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0]
score = 1
for i in list:
    while score < 4:
        if i == 0:
            list.pop(0)
            score = score +1
print(list)
```

I want to print the remaining list after the 4th 0. The list is dynamic and is changed by the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply achieve that without any need of second loop, first write a function that finds the correct index and get the remaining part.

```
def find_index(element, encounter, list):
   for i, v in enumerate(list):
     if v == element:
       encounter -= 1
       if encounter == 0:
         return i

list = [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0]
list[find_index(0, 4, list):]
# >>> [0, 1, 0]
list[find_index(0, 4, list)+1:]
# >>> [1, 0]
```